# Programmatically building SQL query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I’d like to automatically build up a SQL query based on some strings passed in by my users. Are there any helper methods for doing that in the Cloud Spanner APIs?

Answer (score 1):

We strongly recommend that you not generate textual SQL based on untrusted user input. It’s much easier and safer to use [bound parameters](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/reference/rpc/google.spanner.v1#google.spanner.v1.ExecuteSqlRequest), which help you avoid SQL injection attacks.